# elasticsearch query has slow performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have about 3000 documents in my index and the following query is taking about 17 seconds to return 2000 documents.  Is this expected or should I hope for better performance?  I just used the automap feature with the nest client to map the fields, is this good enough?

query:

```
 GET /data/_search?pretty
{
 "_source": ["formName", "appId"],
 "size" :2000,
 "query":
 { 
   "nested":
   {
     "path":"fields",
     "query":
     {
       "bool":
       {
         "should":[
         {"match": {"fields.fieldId": "fdtElem1499Group" }},
          {"match": {"fields.fieldId": "fdtElem360Group" }}

        ]
       }
   },
     "inner_hits": {}
   }
 }
}
```

mapping:

```
{
  "data": {
    "mappings": {
      "formdata": {
        "properties": {
          "appId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "appInstanceId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "createdDate": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "fields": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "fieldId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "fieldName": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "fieldValue": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "formId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "formName": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "lastUpdated": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "organisationGroup_fkey": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "updatedBy": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "groupId": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "userId": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "workflowId": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you need to include the `_source` argument in the query payload. Can you try taking it out.

Comment: I think the `_search` endpoint is also a `POST` request.

Comment: if I take 'source' off, it actually just times out. I think the reason is that for each document, there are about 400 nested fields, so using source, means I only return the 2 I'm wanting.  When I changed the 'GET' to 'POST', it reduced to 12 seconds. Better but still not great.

Comment: Think there is a `"explain": true` argument you can add to the query.

Comment: adding 'explain':true, causes it to time out

Comment: How large is the response in bytes for 2000 rows? using [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-request-scroll.html) might help

Comment: Also switching the match to term on fieldId.keyword field might help. And see if you are getting in terms of scoring this can speed things up.

Comment: What is your ES configuration ? How many boxes and shards you have ?  Are you running other applications on ES box ? Can you check your search queues ? Are you making network request ? That may be a bottleneck. Try profiling your query. I query millions of documents anf 17 seconds are too much for 3000 docs. ES should not behave like this if configured properly.

Comment: Is that the time query took ( returned as a part of response ) in ES ?
17 sec not generally expected - but depends . To start with if you can provide , few sample documents , h/w config - you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the inner_hits from your request. It makes things way slower, especially when you are recovering so many documents (you can take a look to this discusion: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14229). Also like said before, using a scroll could help speed things up